# Bootstrap CSS not working with Flask

Tags: python, css, twitter-bootstrap, flask

*edit
I think the code is correct so maybe it is something to do with Chrome?

*edit 2 included the file structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3OQ6.png)

I have tried adding a Bootstrap pill to my page but the CSS does not seem to be working. I have tried adding other components as well but the CSS does not seem to work for them either.

I have also tried using "cmd shift r" (I am using a mac), but that has not helped either.

Anyone know why this is not working and how to fix it?

I have downloaded and put into the static the folder the bootstrap-dist.

[What the page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irOKT.png)

[The python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZURUp.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Home Page</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1">
  <link type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}"
   rel="stylesheet">
   <!-- how to link an icon
   <link rel="shortcut icon"
   href="{{ url_for('static', filename='icon_name.ico') }}">
   -->
</head>
<header>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="badge">42</span></a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages <span class="badge">3</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
</html>
```

Comment: in what directory you have bootstrap.min.js ?

Comment: bootstrap.min.js is in static/js

Comment: Can you post your project file structure?

Comment: @atwalsh there you go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the HTML code from your question yields different results depending on the version of Bootstrap you reference. It is possible that you are using Bootstrap 4 when you need to be using Bootstrap 3. This would cause the nav pills to show up like the image in your question.

**HTML (from question)**

```
<header>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="badge">42</span></a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages <span class="badge">3</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

**Linking to Bootstrap 3**

[image]

**Linking to Bootstrap 4**

[image]